# Standard proof of permutations of $n$ people standing in line

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, induction

I want to prove the statement: For $n$ people the number of permutations is $n!$. How to prove or justify this statement ?

I think the easiest way is to use induction.

If we have a line of $1$ people the number of permutations is 1.

For $n$ people the number of permutations is $n!$.
Since we have the start we only need to prove that it holds for $n+1$.

$ (n+1)!=(n+1) n! = (n+1) $ "times we can reorder a line of n people"
 = times we can reorder a line of $n+1$ people.

Is this a good argument? Is there a more intuitive or elegant way to show it?

Comment: It seems fine to me...

Comment: But there must be a more elegant way to show it

Comment: You mean the number of *permutations* of $n$ people standing in line.

Comment: Abzal Serekov has provided you with the standard argument.  You could improve your induction argument by observing that for each of the $n!$ ways of arranging $n$ people in line, there are $n + 1$ ways for the $(n + 1)$st person to insert himself or herself in the line (in the $n - 1$ spaces between successive people and at the two ends).  By the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), there are $n!(n + 1) = (n + 1)!$ permutations of $n + 1$ people in line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a row of $n$ places for $n$ people

- For the **first** place you can put any of **$n$** people
- For the **second** place you can put any of **$n-1$** people (since you have already put one in the first place)
- ...
- For the **$n$th** place you can put just **1** person (since you have already put other $n-1$ people to previous $n-1$ places)

So, using multiplication rule there are in total: $n \cdot (n-1) \dots 2 \cdot 1 = n!$ ways to place $n$ people